# How did the USA airport authorities allow the Sunny Leone family to reach the USA during COVID-19 lockdown?

Tags: usa, india, covid-19

How did the USA airport authorities allow the Sunny Leone family to reach the USA during COVID-19 lockdown?

[Source](https://indianexpress.com/article/entertainment/bollywood/sunny-leone-travels-to-the-us-with-family-6404291/)

Comment: She is a US citizen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunny_Leone

Comment: Indian citizen here desperately waiting for flights to open for around 2 months to reach home. :-|

Answer (score 6):

US authorities allowed her and her family to travel to the US by not closing the US border to US citizens.  US citizens are allowed to enter the US, although they are supposed to quarantine themselves under certain conditions.